# Access to port from application

Tags: c#, .net, http, netsh

I need advice.  I am writing a specialized http server application that I want other people to install.  It will probably not use port 80.  If they use their own port they will inevitably get "Access Denied" when trying to start the server.  I know I can run

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

to enable port, say, 8080 from an elevated command line but I don't ever do this for other applications that have similar functionality.  So the question is, how can I get the access from within the application itself?

Comment: You can invoke a process from within the application which users the same command

Comment: Ahh i know this but I think you'd have to invoke the process as an elevated command (administrator) no?

Comment: Did I stump everyone?